# error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: apt, compiling, c

I am trying to install netcdf in order to compiling WRF. However, it shows an error which I do not understand.

[image: error]

and config.log:

```
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by netCDF configure 4.1.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//netcdf --disable-dap --disable-netcdf-4 --disable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = valentina-pc
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.3.0-42-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3070: netCDF 4.1.3
configure:3110: checking build system type
configure:3124: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3144: checking host system type
configure:3157: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3179: checking target system type
configure:3192: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3243: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3311: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3322: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3372: result: yes
configure:3513: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3552: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3565: checking for gawk
configure:3595: result: no
configure:3565: checking for mawk
configure:3581: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:3592: result: mawk
configure:3603: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3625: result: yes
configure:3709: checking user options
configure:3719: checking whether CXX is set to ''
configure:3723: result: no
configure:3727: checking whether FC is set to ''
configure:3731: result: no
configure:3735: checking whether F90 is set to ''
configure:3739: result: no
configure:3743: checking whether a NCIO_MINBLOCKSIZE was specified
configure:3753: result: 256
configure:3761: checking whether udunits is to be built
configure:3770: result: no
configure:3773: checking if fsync support is enabled
configure:3781: result: yes
configure:3790: checking whether extra valgrind tests should be run
configure:3798: result: no
configure:3802: checking whether we should try to build netCDF-4
configure:3810: result: no
configure:3827: checking whether libcf is to be built
configure:3836: result: no
configure:3840: checking whether reading of HDF4 SD files is to be enabled
configure:3848: result: no
configure:3852: checking whether to fetch some sample HDF4 files from Unidata ftp site to test HDF4 reading (requires wget)
configure:3865: result: no
configure:3869: checking whether parallel I/O for classic and 64-bit offset files using parallel-netcdf is to be enabled
configure:3877: result: no
configure:3881: checking whether new netCDF-4 C++ API is to be built
configure:3892: result: no
configure:3896: checking whether extra example tests should be run
configure:3904: result: no
configure:3908: checking whether parallel IO tests should be run
configure:3916: result: no
configure:3920: checking whether a default chunk size in bytes was specified
configure:3930: result: 4194304
configure:3939: checking whether a maximum per-variable cache size for HDF5 was specified
configure:3949: result: 67108864
configure:3958: checking whether a number of chunks for the default per-variable cache was specified
configure:3968: result: 10
configure:3977: checking whether a default file cache size for HDF5 was specified
configure:3987: result: 4194304
configure:3996: checking whether a default file cache maximum number of elements for HDF5 was specified
configure:4006: result: 1009
configure:4015: checking whether a default cache preemption for HDF5 was specified
configure:4025: result: 0.75
configure:4034: checking whether netCDF-4 logging is enabled
configure:4042: result: no
configure:4046: checking whether cdmremote client is to be built
configure:4056: result: no
configure:4060: checking whether DAP client is to be built
configure:4068: result: no
configure:4095: checking for style of include used by make
configure:4123: result: GNU
configure:4193: checking for gcc
configure:4220: result: gcc
configure:4449: checking for C compiler version
configure:4458: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4469: $? = 0
configure:4458: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
configure:4469: $? = 0
configure:4458: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4469: $? = 1
configure:4458: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4469: $? = 1
configure:4489: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4511: gcc  -I/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/include /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/lib conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/lib: No such file or directory
configure:4515: $? = 1
configure:4553: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "netCDF"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "netcdf"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.1.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "netCDF 4.1.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support-netcdf@unidata.ucar.edu"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "netcdf"
| #define VERSION "4.1.3"
| #define NCIO_MINBLOCKSIZE 256
| #define USE_FSYNC 1
| #define DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE 4194304
| #define MAX_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE 67108864
| #define DEFAULT_CHUNKS_IN_CACHE 10
| #define CHUNK_CACHE_SIZE 4194304
| #define CHUNK_CACHE_NELEMS 1009
| #define CHUNK_CACHE_PREEMPTION 0.75
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4558: error: in `/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3':
configure:4560: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-I/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/include
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=g++
ac_cv_env_F77_set=set
ac_cv_env_F77_value=gfortran
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=-m64
ac_cv_env_FC_set=set
ac_cv_env_FC_value=gfortran
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=-m64
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/lib
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/missing --run tar'
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='mawk'
BINFILE_NAME=''
BUILD_BENCHMARKS_FALSE=''
BUILD_BENCHMARKS_TRUE=''
BUILD_CDMREMOTE_FALSE=''
BUILD_CDMREMOTE_TRUE=''
BUILD_CXX4_FALSE=''
BUILD_CXX4_TRUE=''
BUILD_CXX_FALSE=''
BUILD_CXX_TRUE=''
BUILD_C_FALSE=''
BUILD_C_TRUE=''
BUILD_DAP_FALSE=''
BUILD_DAP_TRUE=''
BUILD_DLL_FALSE=''
BUILD_DLL_TRUE=''
BUILD_EXAMPLES_FALSE=''
BUILD_EXAMPLES_TRUE=''
BUILD_F77_FALSE=''
BUILD_F77_TRUE=''
BUILD_F90_FALSE=''
BUILD_F90_TRUE=''
BUILD_LIBCF_FALSE=''
BUILD_LIBCF_TRUE=''
BUILD_PARALLEL_FALSE=''
BUILD_PARALLEL_TRUE=''
BUILD_UDUNITS_FALSE=''
BUILD_UDUNITS_TRUE=''
BUILD_UTILITIES_FALSE=''
BUILD_UTILITIES_TRUE=''
BUILD_V2_FALSE=''
BUILD_V2_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/include'
CROSS_COMPILING_FALSE=''
CROSS_COMPILING_TRUE=''
CXX='g++'
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_DAP_LONG_TESTS_FALSE=''
ENABLE_DAP_LONG_TESTS_TRUE=''
ENABLE_DAP_REMOTE_TESTS_FALSE=''
ENABLE_DAP_REMOTE_TESTS_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRA_EXAMPLE_TESTS_FALSE=''
EXTRA_EXAMPLE_TESTS_TRUE=''
EXTRA_TESTS_FALSE=''
EXTRA_TESTS_TRUE=''
F77='gfortran'
FC='gfortran'
FCFLAGS='-m64'
FCFLAGS_f90=''
FFLAGS='-m64'
FGREP=''
FTPBINDIR=''
GREP=''
HAS_CXX=''
HAS_DAP=''
HAS_F77=''
HAS_F90=''
HAS_HDF4=''
HAS_HDF5=''
HAS_NC2=''
HAS_NC4=''
HAS_PNETCDF=''
HAS_SZLIB=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INTERNAL_OCLIB_FALSE=''
INTERNAL_OCLIB_TRUE=''
LARGE_FILE_TESTS_FALSE=''
LARGE_FILE_TESTS_TRUE=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS='/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/lib'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MOD_FLAG=''
NC_FLIBS=''
NC_LIBS=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NMFLAGS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='netcdf'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='support-netcdf@unidata.ucar.edu'
PACKAGE_NAME='netCDF'
PACKAGE_STRING='netCDF 4.1.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='netcdf'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='4.1.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
TEST_F77_FALSE=''
TEST_F77_TRUE=''
TEST_PARALLEL_FALSE=''
TEST_PARALLEL_TRUE=''
UPPER_CASE_MOD_FALSE=''
UPPER_CASE_MOD_TRUE=''
USE_DAP_FALSE=''
USE_DAP_TRUE=''
USE_DISPATCH_FALSE=''
USE_DISPATCH_TRUE=''
USE_FFIO_FALSE=''
USE_FFIO_TRUE=''
USE_HDF4_FALSE=''
USE_HDF4_FILE_TESTS_FALSE=''
USE_HDF4_FILE_TESTS_TRUE=''
USE_HDF4_TRUE=''
USE_LOGGING_FALSE=''
USE_LOGGING_TRUE=''
USE_NETCDF4_FALSE=''
USE_NETCDF4_TRUE=''
USE_PNETCDF_DIR_FALSE=''
USE_PNETCDF_DIR_TRUE=''
USE_PNETCDF_FALSE=''
USE_PNETCDF_TRUE=''
USE_RENAMEV3_FALSE=''
USE_RENAMEV3_TRUE=''
USE_SZIP_FALSE=''
USE_SZIP_TRUE=''
USE_VALGRIND_TESTS_FALSE=''
USE_VALGRIND_TESTS_TRUE=''
VERSION='4.1.3'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_ct_F77=''
ac_ct_FC=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//netcdf'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='unknown'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "netCDF"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "netcdf"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.1.3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "netCDF 4.1.3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support-netcdf@unidata.ucar.edu"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "netcdf"
#define VERSION "4.1.3"
#define NCIO_MINBLOCKSIZE 256
#define USE_FSYNC 1
#define DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE 4194304
#define MAX_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE 67108864
#define DEFAULT_CHUNKS_IN_CACHE 10
#define CHUNK_CACHE_SIZE 4194304
#define CHUNK_CACHE_NELEMS 1009
#define CHUNK_CACHE_PREEMPTION 0.75
```

Comment: So the underlying issue seems to be `/home/valentina/miWRF/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES//grib2/lib: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please don't post command line results as image. Rather paste them into a `code` section. This will make the messages of your question indexable by Google and others.

Comment: »» trying to install netcdf «« : `$ sudo apt install libnetcdf-dev` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netcdf&searchon=names